# IIS7.5 Application Request Routing (ARR) proxy to multiple ports

Tags: wcf, iis, windows-server-2008, arr, web-farm-framework

I have an unusual scenario, where I am trying to scale a WCF service that isn't thread safe. I have four instances of the service running on a single 4-core server, in four separate IIS web sites, with CPU affinity enabled. The sites are bound to ports 8022, 8023, 8024 and 8025.

My question is: can I use Application Request Routing (ARR) to load balance requests to a single port (80) across these four sites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know you can't use the Webfarm-Framework for balancing between different ports on one Server. Maybe because from a failure safety perspective it dosn't make sence.
A workaround is to add some additional IPs to your Webserver and configure your 4 web sites bindings to listen on the same port but on different IPs.
So you cann set up a web farm with 4 different IPs as servers which in fact are locatet on the same physical machine.

hope this helps.
Best regards,
Peter

Comment: I hadn't thought of using multiple IPs - thanks for the idea! In this particular scenario fault tolerance is less of a concern than being able to process multiple simultaneous requests.